# Taking a prisoner's head off and mounting it on a pedestal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I think this was a short story. The story is written from the perspective of the prisoner.

The man wakes up having gone through an operation to have his head detached from his body. The head is still alive, mounted on a pedestal with machinery to keep him alive. Once a day a woman comes around to clean his head and brush his teeth. He has the option to swallow, and the stuff will go down a hole for refuse. He has no choice but to think about what he has done.

Because he has no lungs he does not need to breathe, and he can't talk. He has no heart to beat either. He's just a head on a pedestal. he can't escape until his sentence is over, at which point he will be reattached to a new body.

This was written back when they were doing experiments with animal heads connected up to tubes to see how long they could stay alive on life support.

That's about all I remember.

Comment: This rings a very vague bell, but I have the idea it's a non-SF author and the story is about the moral issues rather than about the SF aspects of removing and reattaching heads. Does that chime with your memory?

Answer (score 4):

There's a similar scene, but there are too many differences for this to be the answer, in Orson Scott Card's *Wyrm*.

There, someone's head can be detached upon death (or *causing* death), and revived by specialized biological constructs. Its sensations can both be read (the ultimate lie detector) and written (the ultimate torture instrument).

This is used for a variety of purposes: a trusted counselor's head can be kept alive for a thousand years to give valuable advice (see image for the gory details after Lord Peace's demise, as witnessed by his daughter Patience). Or a criminal can be made suffer for the same period. Or some sort of immortality can be thus obtained (there's a ship captain further on in the book who's a detached head, has a trained monkey to blow his "breath bladder" allowing him to speak). I seem to remember that the current king had a hated wife mounted as a head in his bedchamber to force her to look at his lovemaking with his concubines.

Card often expanded short stories or recycled clever ideas in his books; I half wonder if the story you read might come from an early seed or contribution to *Wyrm*.

> She had heard and seen the process often enough before. It took less
>   than an hour to link the headworms with the nerves in her father's
>   spine. She watched coldly as her father's face sometimes writhed in
>   agony, for most nerves caused pain when they were awakened by the
>   headworms. Finally, though, the headkeeper dismissed his apprentices.
>   The physical process was finished.
>
> His neck bones were attached to a rack, his windpipe was attached to
>   the breath bladder, and his neck was just touching the gel that
>   sustained the headworms that clung to his nerves and the gools that
>   sent tendrils through his blood vessels. They would keep his head
>   alive, his memories intact, for the next thousand years-or until a
>   King grew tired of him and had his head thrown out.
>
> The headkeeper talked to him then, asking him questions.
>
> He taught the headworms by dripping certain chemicals into the
>   canister when Lord Peace's answers were forthright, and other
>   chemicals when he hesitated or seemed agitated. The headworms quickly
>   learned which of the head's nerves caused pleasure and which caused
>   suffering.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The person was definitely a prisoner and definitely placed on a pedestal because of his crimes. The apparatus that kept him alive was machinery. His thoughts were also about what would happen if the woman who came around to wash his head, didn't. Being a head, the prison was fool proof.